# Can 'a-frame-physics' be used with 'a-text'?

Tags: physics, aframe

I am trying to get a text entity to fall in a scene. `dynamic-body` works on other elements (sphere, cube, etc.) but not on `a-text`.

Here is my glitch:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ruby-stork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic shape detection in `dynamic-body` doesn't handle text. You can apply a physics body shape manually instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The text shall fall. - A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The text shall fall.">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/v2.1.0/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = () => {
        const text = document.querySelector('a-text')
        // Cannon boxes use 'halfExtents', side length / 2
        const shape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(0.5, 0.1, 0.5))
        // body may or may not be ready when onload occurs
        if (text.body) {
          text.body.addShape(shape)
        } else {
          text.addEventListener('body-loaded', () => text.body.addShape(shape))
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <!-- "shape:none" to disable auto detection. Required if combining text and geometry in same entity tree -->
      <a-text dynamic-body="shape:none" position="-1 2 -3" value="Cylinder falls, this does too." height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" ></a-text>
      <a-cylinder dynamic-body position="1 5 -3" rotation="12 0 0" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane static-body position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="14" height="14" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the text on a thin box.

`<a-entity geometry="primitive: box; depth: 0.01" text="value: HEY" dynamic-body>`